# JavaScript value in HTML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implemented that in **JavaScript**:

```
$('#dash_adc_avg').html(adc_avg);
```

And this in **HTML**:
(part **A**)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="big-text"  id="dash_adc_avg"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            Energy Monitor AS
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this in **HTML**:
(part **B**, same file as part A)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="widget index">
                <header>
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Status word <small> </small>
                    </h4>
                </header>                                           
                <div class="body">
                    - Test: <div class="text"  id="dash_adc_avg"></div><br>
```

etc.

Unfortunately, the visualization of the content from `var adc_avg` works properly for "part A" ONLY. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

By the way and independent: I'm looking for a way to visualize JSON-Data (as Objects) on the website, without changing them. Any ideas?

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... use a class instead to group similar elements like `<div class="text dash_adc_avg"  id="dash_adc_avg"></div>` then `$('.dash_adc_avg').html(adc_avg);`

Comment: The second part of your question has nothing to do with the first part. If you have another question, please ask that separately.

Comment: Thank all of you! Perfect, was easier than expected. @James Donnelly: you're right, I should ask in another question for the JSON visualization, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`id` attribute section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) of the HTML specification:

> The id attribute specifies its element's **unique identifier** (ID).
>
> **The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree** and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

IDs must be unique in HTML. Because of this, JavaScript only ever looks for one instance of an ID and then stops searching. In your case, the ID being pulled is the one in part A - your code never bothers looking further than that.

Change your "dash_adc_avg" ID into a class instead:

```
<!-- Part A -->
<div class="big-text dash_adc_avg"></div>

<!-- Part B -->
- Test: <div class="text dash_adc_avg"></div><br>
```

Then with your jQuery select on the class instead of the ID:

```
$('.dash_adc_avg').html(adc_avg);
```

---

I'm not going to bother answering the second part of your question, which is about visualising JSON data, as it has absolutely nothing to do with the main part of the question and is completely separate. Please ask that as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

An identity has to be unique in the page.

It's still *possible* to use the `id` attribute to find the elements, but then you have to use it as an attribute, not as an identity:

```
$('[id=dash_adc_avg]').html(adc_avg);
```

Generally a class is used instead when you want to put it on multiple elements. There is no benefit of keeping the dupliate `id` attributes as they don't work as identities.

Comment: Whilst this may work, I feel advising someone to go against the HTML specification by using `[id=dash_adc_avg]` is a terrible idea...

Answer (score 0):

You are using duplicate id's `dash_adc_avg` which is a invalid HTML instead of id's use class and modify your Jquery selector as shown :-

```
$('.dash_adc_avg').html(adc_avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use class when you are using same name for more than once on same page in your html:

```
$('.dash_adc_avg').html(adc_avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to use the same id tag on multiple places, I would suggest that you instead use class for your **dash_adc_avg**

```
$('.dash_adc_avg').html(adc_avg)
```

**And this in HTML: (part A)**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="big-text"  class="dash_adc_avg"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            Energy Monitor AS
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And this in HTML: (part B, same file as part A)**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="widget index">
                <header>
                    <h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Status word <small> </small>
                    </h4>
                </header>                                           
                <div class="body">
                    - Test: <div class="text"  class="dash_adc_avg"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id must be unique and if not the first element found by that id will be selected.

For multiple selection for same thing/functionality use class instead of id.